# I need to create a vba script or macro that can transpose and format data all at once

Tags: vba, excel

I have found the code

```
Sub Test()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Dim LastRow As Long
     LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows,SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
     Dim lColumn As Long
     Dim x As Long
     Dim rng As Range
     For Each rng In Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
     lColumn = Cells(rng.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
     For x = 1 To lColumn - 2
        Range(Cells(rng.Row, "A"), Cells(rng.Row, "B")).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = rng.Offset(0, x + 1)
    Next x
Next rng
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I am trying to modify it to suit my needs but it isn't quite doing what I need it to do.
Basically, my table is like this:

```
A         B  C        D
FILENAME  ID FIELD1   FIELD2
1         2  3        4
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
A FILENAME 1
B  ID 2
C FIELD1 3
D FIELD2 4
```

however, sometimes there may be more columns or rows associated with a given part of the range that is related to a set of data. right now the columns that

I don't know nearly enough about excel and vba to modify this code to do that, but it would be nice if I could.

below are a couple of links that explain closely how I want the final table to look.
http://pastebin.com/1i5MqTL7
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwl28.jpg

Comment: a) Select the **A** above **FILENAME** and tap Ctrl+A. b) Tap Ctrl+C. c) Select the top-left cell for your destination. d) Choose Paste Special, Transpose or Alt+E, S, E, <enter>.

Comment: I know how to transpose using keyboard commands, but I want more functionality than that. because there are thousands of lines and I want them to be separated by filename.

Comment: Is it possible to give a better example of input and desired output? That example on pastebin didnt give me the necessary logic...

Comment: Here is a link to an imgur album which shows the data in it's current form and how I want it to look. http://imgur.com/a/PKAcy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID's are not unique product pointers, but that's the REAL world. Different considerations and assumptions about the consistency of your input data, but try this:

```
Private Sub TransposeBits()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
'start will be the starting row of each set
Dim start As Long
start = 2

'finish will be the last row of each set
Dim finish As Long
finish = start

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'printRow will keep track of where to paste-transpose each set
Dim printRow As Long
printRow = lastRow + 2

'lastCol will measure the column count of each set
Dim lastCol As Long

'Just dealing with a single entry here - delete as necessary
If lastRow < 3 Then
    lastCol = Cells(start, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
    With ws
        .Range(.Cells(start, 1), .Cells(finish, lastCol)).Copy
        .Cells(printRow, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'in the trivial case, we can exit the sub after dealing with the one-line transpose
    Exit Sub
End If

'more general case
For i = 3 To lastRow
    If Not Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & i - 1).Value Then
        'the value is different than above, so set the finish to the above row
        finish = i - 1
        lastCol = Cells(start, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
        'copy the range from start row to finish row and paste-transpose
        With ws
            .Range(.Cells(start, 1), .Cells(finish, lastCol)).Copy
            .Cells(printRow, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
        End With
        'after finding the end of a set, reset the start and printRow variable
        start = i
        printRow = printRow + lastCol
    End If
Next i

'here we deal with the last set after running through the loop
finish = lastRow
lastCol = Cells(start, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
With ws
        .Range(.Cells(start, 1), .Cells(finish, lastCol)).Copy
        .Cells(printRow, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This does Exactly what I wanted. Thank you for notating it so that I can understand it as well!

Comment: Glad to help. Note that I'm not a fan of too much copy-paste in VBA. If your input rows are many thousands, then I would prefer to use arrays and dictionaries/collections to load up the data, then print out an array to the sheet in one hit. But this should do for you....

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Paste Special that @Jeeped uses - just write it in code:

```
Sub TransposeData()

    Dim rLastCell As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'NB:  If the sheet is empty this will throw an error.
        Set rLastCell = .Cells.Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

        'Copy everything from A1 to the last cell.
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), rLastCell).Copy

        'Paste/Transpose in column A, one row below last row containing data.
        .Cells(rLastCell.Row + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The rows are of varying length, so this does not quite fix the issue, but this does at least partially work